# How to use the href link to navigate to angular route?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular6, angular-routing

I send the account activation email to the user. after click user activation button redirected my angular application. but not redirect the accurate route. actually redirected home route.

how to executed ActivationComponent.ts file use email activate button

**Application Route**

```
   { path: 'home', component: SearchBarComponent },   
   { path: 'user/activation/:email/:token',component: ActivationComponent }   
   { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

**Email link href**

> `www.example.com/#/user/activation?email=example@gmail.lk&token=Mo0hFjfKqY6tPmDzAkiRmEKE5aQDzOtDTGleJmdQsY2DtVOOPnn0Uas1REZaecCE`

**ActivationComponent**

```
import { SnotifyService } from 'ng-snotify';
import { AuthenticationService } from './../../../http/services/authentication.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Params } from '../../../../../node_modules/@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-activation',
  templateUrl: './activation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./activation.component.scss']
})
export class ActivationComponent implements OnInit {

  private email: string;
  private token: string;
  public message: string;
  constructor(
    private router: ActivatedRoute,
    private route: Router,
    public auth: AuthenticationService,
    private snotifyService: SnotifyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.queryParams
    .subscribe(params => {
      this.email = params.email;
      this.token = params.token;
    });
    console.log(this.email);
    console.log(this.token);
    if (this.email && this.token) {
      this.auth.auActivation(this.email, this.token).subscribe(
        req => {
         this.message = req['success'] ;
        }
      );
    }
  }


  requestLink(): void {
    this.auth.auRequestActivation().subscribe(
      req => {
        this.snotifyService.success('varification email request sended!', 'Success');
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Can you help me? how to solve this problem. given this example or tutorial link

Comment: just change the url to this: `www.example.com/#/user/activation/example@gmail.lk/Mo0hFjfKqY6tPmDzAkiRmEKE5aQDzOtDTGleJmdQsY2DtVOOPnn0Uas1REZaecCE`

Comment: @Jacopo can't solver this problem using your answer.

Comment: I'll post a better answer in a sec

Comment: your action (activation...) should be done inside subscribe method. In your case, console.log(...) is executed during ngOnInit dans not when new params are updated.

Answer (score 0):

Since your route is `'user/activation/:email/:token'` it means that the url to get the params should be something like this : `.../user/activation/your@email.com/someRandomNumberAndLetterToken`

to catch them, add

```
private activatedroute: Activatedroute
```

in your constructor.

Add this code add the very start of your `OnInit` function

```
this.email = this.activatedroute.snapshot.params['email'];
this.token = this.activatedroute.snapshot.params['token'];
```

Then you can continue executing your script. I have attached a photo to show you what you get in console (in my case) :

[image: snapshot debug]

[image: Routes]